# ASP.NET MVC with composition pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I need my controllers to have several functionalities, e.g.,

- Some of the controllers save my entities to a database, so I use the Repository pattern here (passing the Repository in the constructor).
- Some of the controllers, on the other hand, do this PLUS sending my entities to an external service. In this case I pass the service client in the constructor of the Controller too.

Since my controller cannot inherit from two classes, e.g.,

- DbEntityController: The one that deals with a database repository.
- ServiceEntityController: The one that deals with a remote service client.

Can you give me a couple of advises about how to implement a sort of composition pattern for MVC Controllers? I am actually concerned about the URL routing etc. Is this going to work if my action methods delegate their tasks to an "inner" controller.

Any ideas will help a lot!

UPDATE:

These are my constructors more or less (I use DI with Unity by the way)

```js
DbEntityController(IDbRepository<TEntity>)

ServiceEntityController(IServiceRepository<TEntity>)

OrderController(IDbRepository<IOrder>, IServiceRepository<IOrder>)

AddressController(IDbRepository<IAddress>)
```

- Somehow OrderController inherits from both DbEntityController and ServiceEntityController.

Comment: Sounds like you want to inject these dependencies into your controllers.  Take a look at dependency injection.  There are nuget packages for the DI containers that will integrate this into your project.  I can give you an example using Unity if you'd like.

Comment: I actually use DI with unity to inject my dependencies. However, apart of injecting the dependencies I can reuse the work I do with these dependencies.

Comment: Martín, you can use the at sign to reply the other's comments like this @BigDaddy am I right?